# Prove that $a^2 = b^2 \rightarrow (a = b $ or $ a = -b )$, where $a,b \in C $ and C is a field

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem**

C is a field and $a,b \ \epsilon \ C$

Prove:
$a^2 = b^2 \rightarrow a = b \vee a = -b $

How would I go about proving this. I'm not entirely sure, what this implies. I know that for something to be a field it must meet these requirements:

$(C,+)$ is abelian.

$(C - {e},\cdot)$ is abelian, meaning that multiplication is abelian only when zero is excluded.

$\forall x,y\ \epsilon \ C, x(y+z) = xy + xz$

However, I'm not sure how exactly I would use these things to prove that.

Comment: Hint: $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: I see, thank you for that hint. Is there some way to mark that as an answer?

Comment: You may don't know but just for your culture there is a bit of quantum mechanic in your question ! :)

Comment: There is an answer by now.  After a while you should accept an answer. Note that we need to use the fact that if $xy$ is $0$ then $x=0$ or $y=0$ (or both). This may already have been proved in your course. Quick proof: If for example $x\ne 0$, multiply both sides by the inverse of $x$. We get $x^{-1}(xy)=(x^{-1})(0)$. But the left side is $y$. The right side is $0$. This may already have been proved in your course, that $(w)(0)=0$ for any $w$. If it has not, you can prove it by using $w(0+0)=w(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$a^2-b^2=0\implies (a+b)(a-b)=0\implies $ either $a-b=0$ or $a+b=0$ (Why?)

Since a field is an integral domain and so has no zero divisors